# Wordpress is ignoring Unicode Chars in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, permalinks

I am using wordpress with this type of permalink:

/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

if I use this type of url:
example.com/2010/03/तकनीक

it treats this url like this example.com/2010/03/ (By ignoring unicode chars)
and displays March 2010 archive list.

if I use english url:
example.com/2010/03/technology
then it works perfectly.

This problem occurs even on tags page:
for example  example.com/tag/इंटरनेट is treated like example.com/tag/ and displays 404 page.

Why wordpress is ignoring unicode chars?

If I use default querystring structure then it works perfectly even with unicode characters.

Server Info:
IIS7 Win2008 Server (Url rewriting enabled)
Wordpress 2.9.2

Comment: What are you using to rewrite URLs?

Answer (score 11):

For an overview of the problem, review:

http://ruslany.net/2010/03/important-update-for-iis-7-0-fastcgi-module/

this refers you to the now outdated:

http://ruslany.net/2010/02/fastcgi-module-differences-across-iis-versions/

My own situation was fixed by applying Win 7 SP1 but, interestingly, I was still left with applying the registry hack that is described in the Hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277918

Answer (score 4):

I am running WAMP server on local machine. I tested $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] on my IIS7 web server and found that it has some unicode problem. Wordpress uses path_info to handle urls.
I created a file test.php with following code:

If I request [http://example.com/test.php/कुछशब्द/कुछऔरशब्द/english](http://example.com/test.php/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6/english)

then I get this output

----****----

/???????/?????????/english
----****----
path_info is converting unicode hindi chars to ?????.
That means there is some problem in path_info variable in my server.
Do you know any setting IIS7 that can cause such type of problem?

The same code works perfectly fine on my local Apache Windows server.

Answer (score 1):

The [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277918) provides a hotfix which didn't work for my windows version and/or code to use using **Start > Run** which also wasn't effective and didn't add the registry key for some reason in my case on **Windows 7 Ultimate and IIS 7.5.7600**

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\w3svc\Parameters /v FastCGIUtf8ServerVariables /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d REQUEST_URI\0PATH_INFO
```

I had to do one of the following choices:

**1) Add the Reg. Key manually** under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\w3svc\Parameters by adding new Multi-string value >> 
Value Name : FastCGIUtf8ServerVariables 
Value Data (two lines): 
REQUEST_URI
PATH_INFO

**2 ) Execute the code using cmd.exe as an administrator** then paste the code and excute

In both ways remember to execute the iisreset command on cmd.exe as administrator after the previous step.