# Wordpress permalinks are ignoring Unicode characters in URL

Tags: wordpress, unicode, iis-6, windows-server-2003

There is some problem with pretty permalinks of wordpress on my server.

My permalink structure is :

/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

it ignores the unicode characters on the URL.

for example, if I use www.mydomain.com/2012/01/سلام  , wordpress ignores the unicode part (سلام) and shows the www.mydomain.com/2012/01/ content. (archive page)

and if I use www.mydomain.com/tag/وردپرس , it shows 404 page. I think because there isn't www.mydomain.com/tag/ page.

but everything is correct with english names.
for example, these pages can show correctly:
www.mydomain.com/2012/01/hello-world
www.mydomain.com/tag/wordpress

My server is **IIS6 Windows 2003 on a Shared hosting** without URL rewriting (I'm using that type of permalink structure because of this) Wordpress 3.3.1

***This question is not same as [Wordpress is ignoring Unicode Chars in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473812/wordpress-is-ignoring-unicode-chars-in-url)  because that question asks about IIS7 and Windows server 2008, but I'm asking about IIS6 and Windows Server 2003.***

Comment: And you are sure it's not the same problem and the registry hack presented in the other question doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Pekka Yes. because the hotfixes that are in answers of that question are for IIS7. and I don't find anything about IIS6.

Comment: @Pekka I have shared hosting. and I don't know about registry hack. I may ask my hosting provider to apply some hotfixes, not registry hacks!

Comment: Right, I see. I can't see anything for IIS6 either, strange